# What is meaning of x1, x2 behind hexa javascript variables?

Tags: javascript

For eg.

```
function _0xe680x1(_0xe680x1, _0xe680x2, _0xe680x3)
```

What is meaning of x1, x2 or x3 behind these variable?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Some context could help.

Comment: The author ofthe code should know. First question, are these variables or functions ? At their respective declaration site,there maybe  hint in some comments. Anything else is wild guessing, identifier are names only after all. _My_ wild guess would be that your code originates with some compiler that uses js as intermediate language or some other code generator or it stems from a source code garbler (I wouldn't be completely satisfied with any of these hypotheses, btw).